# ruby equivalent of python request session

Tags: python, ruby, python-requests, net-http, unirest

I want to send requests over session object in Ruby to get data from authentication required API endpoint. I did this with Python as follows:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.post("https://test.url.com/mobile/User/logIn?username=test.user@gmail.com&password=123456abc")
s.get("https://test.url.com/mobile/User/Order/MyOrders")
```

I want to do this in Ruby but couldn't find a library which holds the session information. I have tried Net::HTTP and Unirest, but I guess they don't have this feature. They just suggesting to get cookies from login and use it in the header of next following requests.

How can do this in Ruby?

Comment: Maybe `https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html` could serve your needs

Comment: @simplaY link is broken.